# Guzzlehttp client connection refused over non standard port

Tags: http, docker, curl, php-curl, guzzle

I'm running a few containers using docker-compose.

One of the services I added recently is exposed on port `3000`

Any request made to this service using guzzle throws the following error:

`cURL error 7: Failed to connect to service-stub port 3000: Connection refused (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)`

It works if I change the port to `5000`, however I have another service using that port hence need to run the new service on a different port.

Anyone know how to get around this issue?